# Regular (AUTO)VACUUM in Postgres database does not release disk space taken by vacuum overhead

Tags: postgresql, vacuum, autovacuum, postgresql-16

I have running Postgres instance (version 16.1) in AWS with one table that has following schema:

| Column | Type | Modifiers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user_id | integer | not null default nextval('profile_user_id_seq'::regclass) |
| last_seen | timestamp with time zone | not null |
| data | jsonb[] | not null |

There is primary key on `user_id` column (b-tree to ensure uniqueness) and also hash-index on same `user_id` column and additional b-tree index on `last_seen`.

`data` column is array of JSON documents with structure:

```
{
  key1: str # ~64chars
  key2: str # ~64chars
  key3: int[128]
  key4: str # datetime in iso format
}
```

On top of that, there is ongoing perf-test (running for several days) that:

- 150 times per second selects entire row for randomly chosen user
- 75 times per second there is update of a single random row.

  - During that update, `last_seen` is set to current datetime
  - Random item is appended to `data` array
  - It is ensured that length `data` array does not exceed 50 items:

```
INSERT INTO profile (user_id, last_seen, data) 
VALUES 
  (%user_id, %last_seen, %data), 
  (%user_id, %last_seen, %data) ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT pk_profile DO 
UPDATE 
SET 
  last_seen = %last_seen, 
  data = trim_array(
    array_cat(excluded.data, profile.data), 
    greatest(
      array_length(
        array_cat(excluded.data, profile.data), 1        
      ) - 50, 
      0
    )
  )
```

The automatic vaccum on the table is turned off and instead I have pg_cron job that runs `VACUUM profile` each day at 22PM.

But when I check AWS console and FreeStorageSpace metric, I see that every single vacuum run takes 2-5GB of disk space. The only way how to recover it is of course running `VACUUM FULL`.

[image: Free space in AWS console]

During the day, when vacuum is not running, the free disk space is constant. That suggests that vacuum is doing it's job and it is marking dead tuples as re-usable again. Every single update therefore does not take new disk space and instead old rows marked as free during the vacuum run are re-used again.

I have three possible explanations why this is happening:

1. Deletes and updates that happen during vacuum run can't be handled by vacuum
2. Each vacuum run has some disk overhead that is not fully returned back to OS.
3. Values in `data` column are stored as TOAST and when they items are added or deleted there is increasing fragmentation.

But all those explanations are very unlikely to me.

What is the real cause? Can this be prevented and ensured that if I have constant number of rows in the table and constant number of items in the `data` column, the used disk space will be also constant?

I tried to test both automatic Postgres vacuum and scheduled vacuum using pg_cron extension. I also tried to run the test for several days (3 weeks) with the assumption that free disk space might eventually stabilize.

Comment: No idea what is going on there, but disabling autovacuum sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Same thing happens also for autovacuum runs.

Comment: Perhaps your table is just gradually growing, and the bumps are `VACUUM` writing lots of WAL (which gets deleted again).

Comment: What is `VACUUM profile` doing? That is not a standard Postgres command. This *During the day, when vacuum is not running, the free disk space is constant. That suggests that vacuum is doing it's job and it is marking dead tuples as re-usable again.* seem to contradict, it needs more explanation.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver  "profile" is not a keyword.  It is the name of a table which is being vacuumed.

Comment: What indexes exist? Are they getting larger? Monitoring only at the disk level leaves a lot of ambiguity. Monitor the size of the table proper, the TOAST table, and the indexes, separately.  Then when you do VACUUM FULL, which of those things is getting smaller?

Comment: @jjanes. Memo to self, coffee first then comment.

Comment: @jjanes Thanks for the hint. I will monitor size of the table (data, indexes, toast table) for several days and then check which one is actually getting bigger.

Comment: With so many updates I would see if HOT updates could reduce the need for vacuum. Lower the fill factor and check pg_stat_user_tables to see if it works

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe no, the table size is still the same (same number of rows, same number of items inside data array). Also notice that free disk does not shrink during the day but only after VACUUM run.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I'm afraid that HOT updates are not possible in my case, since I have an index on column last_seen which is also updated in that update query. Or do I get it wrong? (I've added the information about indexes to my original question)

Comment: I’m afraid you’re right, but check your stats.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I'm now exporting values from pg_stat_all_tables  as prometheus metrics. I checked the n_live_tup which is constant (20M for profile, 60M for toast), n_dead_tup which goes gradually up and it is decreased almost to 0 after vaccum and n_tup_hot_upd which is constantly 0 (because I'm updating also last_seen which has index). Is ther any other metric I should look?
I was also thinking about separating last_seen to standalone table. So the profile update (appending and trimming profile items) will do HOT update in the "big" table and regular update in the small "last_seen" table

Comment: @jjanes I'm now looking at data size for last few day. According to values from pg_catalog.pg_statio_user_tables, pg_indexes_size as well as pg_relation_size goes up. But the most space is taken by pg_total_relation_size(relid) - pg_indexes_size(relid) - pg_relation_size(relid) => TOAST. When I do VACUUM FULL, everything goes smaller to their original values.

Comment: Why did you turn autovacuum off? Because it looks like you need a pretty aggressive autovacuum process to keep up with all the updates.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Because of performance reasons - running vacuum has big impact on performance (duration) of SELECT * FROM profile WHERE user_id = :user_id. And with my high update rate (75/second) it was invoked every 8 hours and running for almost 2 hours. So I decided to schedule it on 22PM every night. But the disk space was decreasing even with each autovacuum run. Not so much per one run, but decrease of free disk space per 2 days was almost the same - approx 5GB
PS I know I can mitigate the impact of autovacuum run by setting autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay and autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit.

Comment: `it was invoked every 8 hours and running for almost 2 hours.` that tells me the configuration was wrong. My first impression is that you needed something that would run every few minutes, for just a few (milli-) seconds. You can set this on server level but also on table level, it's up to you.